# Hide "last name" on the edit-account page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am currently using woocommerce and have form-edit-account.php file.

I'd like to get answer about how to hide "last name"field and make it as non-required field on the front end. Following is the codes from form-edit-account.php file

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<form action="" method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' );          ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
</p>
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
</p>
<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" class="input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend><?php _e( 'Password Change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password_current"><?php _e( 'Current Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'New Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm New Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<p>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php _e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
```

I would appreicate for your helps

Comment: There is no answer in this file, this is just the form display. From here, you'd simply zap out the `<span class="required">*</span>` and look for the required field validation in the file that processes the form, or somewhere in a configuration/settings file for the software.

Comment: He is using woocommerce if you modify the framework how you like, it will break & becomes prone to other kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Woocommerce checkout manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/)
Where you have all options to remove any field & its attributes like `required` etc.
hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello,I tried to use that plugin but it didn't affect to my-account/edit-account/ URL page.So i think i need to edit original code from form-edit-account.php file.

Comment: Then the way left is to edit the code, & make the field `display:none` or remove it completely & check first whether jquery validation makes any harm then goto jquery & remove its validation rule for the particular field.